# Outlook 2003 : How to export all e-mail messages in local folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2003, export, extract, local

I want to export some local message folders to zip & send to my colleague in outlook 2003, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Outlook 2003, file > data file management > Add New > then move/copy all messages into new .pst, then find new .pst file that we created and zip it whatever :)
Thanks for all answers...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should go to

- file,
- import and export,
- then export it to a .pst file
- this one zip it (it can be really big, contains all your emails)
- send it maybe by yousendit.com or dushare.com

Good luck, hope this is what you are asking.

Note: I'm on my mac now so this might not be excat exact, but very similar if my memory isn't failing.